# Using redux-connected component as screen in StackNavigator

Tags: react-redux, react-navigation, create-react-native-app

I'm creating an react native app using `create-react-native-app`, `react-navigation` and `react-redux`. I'm trying to add a redux-connected component as a screen into a nested `StackNavigator` (though the nesting seems to not make a difference, it doesn't work either way) and consistently am getting an error message saying `Route 'MilkStash' should declare a screen`. When I remove the redux connection from the `MilkStash.js` file, everything works fine. Any idea how to get this working?

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './src/reducers';
import AppWithNavigation  from './src/AppWithNavigation';

export default () => (
  <Provider store = {createStore(rootReducer)}>
    <AppWithNavigation />
  </Provider>
);
```

**AppWithNavigation.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
import { DrawerNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import MilkStash from './screens'
import { StatsScreen, FAQScreen, AddMilk, AccountScreen } from './screens';

export default class AppWithNavigation extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <MenuNavigator />
    );
  }
}

const MilkNavigator = StackNavigator(
  { Milk: { screen: MilkStash},
    AddMilk: { screen: AddMilk }
  },
);

const AccountNavigator = StackNavigator(
  { Account: {screen: AccountScreen}}
);

const StatsNavigator = StackNavigator(
  { Stats: {screen: StatsScreen }}
);

const FAQNavigator = StackNavigator(
  { FAQ: {screen: FAQScreen}}
)

const MenuNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
    Milk: { screen: MilkNavigator},
    Account: {screen: AccountNavigator},
    Stats: {screen: StatsNavigator},
    FAQ: {screen: FAQNavigator},
  }
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  }
});
```

**MilkStash.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Milk } from '../../core/models/milk';
import styles from './styles.js';

export class MilkStash extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          ....displaying data goes here
      </View>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    milkStash: state.milkStash
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return {
    addMilk: (milk) => dispatch(addMilk(milk)),
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MilkStash);
```

**milk-reducer.js**

```
import {ADD_MILK} from '../constants';

const milkReducer = (state = {milkStash: []}, action = {}) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case ADD_MILK:
      var item = action.payload;
        return state
        .update('milkStash', (milkStash) => 
            {
                var milkStashCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(milkStash));
                milkStashCopy.concat(item);
                return milkStashCopy;

            });
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
export default milkReducer;
```

**reducers.js**

```
export * from './milk.js';

import milkReducer from './milk';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

export default rootReducer = combineReducers({
    milk: milkReducer
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer and thought I would help prevent someone else struggling with this for 3 days. The issue had to do with the way I was importing the exports from `MilkStash.js`. Apparently using `import MilkStash from './screens'` will cause the error but changing it to `import MilkStashContainer from './screens/MilkStash/MilkStash.js` will fix the problem.

Comment: There isn't any `MilkStashContainer` class in your comment. Can you please post this class?